# Decompose a function into a bounded part and a Lipschitz part

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ be a measurable function such that
$$
\sup_{x,y \in \mathbb R^d} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{\max \{1, |x-y| \}} < \infty.
$$

> Are there functions $g,h: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ such that $f = g + h$ and
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \sup_{\substack{x,y \in \mathbb R^d \\x \neq y}} \frac{|g(x) - g(y)|}{|x-y|} + \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^d} |h(x)| &< \infty.
> \end{align*}
> $$
> ?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Triangulate the unit cube $[0,1]^d$ into $d!$ simplices $S_1$, $\ldots$, $S_{d!}$, as in any of the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474880/triangulation-n-dimensional-cube-into-exactly-n-simplices).

Let $g$ satisfy $g(\vec{n}) = f(\vec{n})$ for all $\vec{n} \in \mathbb{Z}^d$, and make it linear on $S_i + \vec{n}$ for every $1 \leq i \leq d!$ and $\vec{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $g$ is Lipschitz and $f - g$ is bounded.

Comment: One does not even need triangulation, since any scalar Lipschitz function on a subset of a metric space can be extended to a Lipschitz function on the full space with the same Lipschitz constant.  Since the restriction of $f$ to say ${\bf Z}^d$ is already Lipschitz, just extend each component to get $g$.  (Presumably the general theory of quasi-isometries would also handle this question, though I didn't see a particularly slick way to do so.)

Comment: Yeah, good point.

Comment: Another approach (relying not on discretization, but on the vector space structure on ${\bf R}^d$) is to take $g$ to be a convolution of $f$ with a standard bump function of unit mass.  Verifying the required estimates is then a nice undergraduate real analysis exercise.